# How to add an active CSS property to a React component?

Tags: css, reactjs

I'm trying to add some styling so that when I click on an item it has a different background color.

I have a class App that imports class ItemSection that imports class ItemList. In both ItemSection and ItemList I have `activeItem: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired` declared in my propTypes.

I think the problem is in my App's render method:

```
  render(){
return(
  <div className = 'app'>
    <div className = 'manipulateItem'> {/*Need a better className*/}
      <ItemSection
        items = {this.state.items}
        addItem = {this.addItem.bind(this)}
        setItem = {this.setItem.bind(this)}
        deleteItem = {this.deleteItem.bind(this)}
        editItem = {this.editItem.bind(this)}
        activeItem = {this.state.activeItem} /*THIS LINE I BELIEVE*/
      />
    </div>
  </div>
)
}
```

And this is my traceback:

bundle.js:1251 Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `activeItem` was not specified in `ItemList`.
    in ItemList (created by ItemSection)
    in ItemSection (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App

Comment: This is coming from ItemList, can you post all three components code please. Also your question is initially about background color and then it switches to propType warning. Just trying to understand what your main concern is.

Answer (score 0):

You are stating in your question that you have `activeItem: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired` declared in your propTypes but you are specifically asking for activeItem in the state object - `activeItem = {this.state.activeItem}`. If you want to use the value of activeItem in the props you are passing to the component, then you must use `this.props.activeItem`.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Well, I changed this and now I'm getting another error:

bundle.js:1251 Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop `activeItem` was not specified in `ItemList`.
    in ItemList (created by ItemSection)
    in ItemSection (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in div (created by App)
    in App

What's weird is that I also have activeItem = {this.props.activeItem} in ItemList.jsx

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly you have app.js which is a component with a render function that is rending `ItemSection` and you on the  `ItemSection` you want to apply a property called `activeItem` and pass that property the value of `this.props.activeItem` which is coming from the apps default props. So if you're getting an error like `error: bundle.js:1251 Warning: Failed prop type: Required prop activeItem was not specified in ItemList.` then that means the `activeItem` property you are passing to `ItemSection` is probably undefined.

Comment: App.jsx is creating ItemSection, which creates ItemList, correct? so if you need to use `this.props.activeItem` to set a className or something just add something like `className={this.props.activeItem ? 'active-item' : ' '}`